# How to read and write session data in AJAX POST request using Laravel?

Tags: php, ajax, http, session, laravel

I have a AJAX post that works in the background, this post request runs a Laravel Controller action that deletes some data from a table, it also sets some Session data. This session data is key called void with a value of true.

```
public function ajaxTest() {

        $flag = Input::get('quit');
        if(isset($flag)) {
          // Roll back transaction table      
          DB::table('mrt_marking_transaction')->where('mrt_marking_transaction_id', Session::get('transactionID'))->delete();
          // Then roll back transaction details table
          DB::table('mra_marking_transaction_answers')->where('mra_marking_transaction_id', Session::get('transactionID'))->delete();  

        }
        Session::put('void', true);
        return Response::json(['flag' => $flag,'sent' => true]);

}
```

The post request will only happen if the current page performs a window.unload. So if the user navigates away from the current page then the POST to that controller action happens. This is the thing though, if they navigate away from the page while still being on the website, I need it to redirect to a specific page.

The way I was going to go about this was the following.

1. Set the session key 'void' as true in ajaxTest controller action
2. In the routes file grab that session key and check its value, if true then use the void route.

The problem is that it never goes into the if statement because Session data with key 'void' doesn't exist, and I don't know why.

```
  if(Session::has('void') and (Session::get('void') == true)) {
      return Redirect::route('void');
  }
```

Comment: Check that the PHPSESSIONID cookie is the same when you visit the web page and for the Ajax call. To do this check the network tab of your developer tools in your browser and look at the cookie header in both of the requests. Both the Ajax call and the visit to the web page need to be on the exact same domain to have the same session id. Also check to make sure the session id is not being reset.